# UK border crossing and electronic privacy: What do I need to know as a visitor?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, privacy

One notices on Border/Immigration programs that the USA and Canada do sometimes request access to your cell phone, laptop, and/or social media information at the airport. It's also all over the [news](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kalevleetaru/2017/01/29/we-already-screen-cell-phones-at-the-border-will-social-media-be-any-different/#6d12dc2e5fa3) and confirmed to be legal according to the laws of both countries.

I am yet to see or read about that for the UK. Are the privacy laws specifically for electronic data such as cell phone, laptops, and social media accounts different for a non-British national at UK border crossings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would be disappointed if you thought you had more rights entering the UK than the US. From this [article](https://www.theverge.com/2017/5/17/15653786/rabbani-encryption-password-charged-terrorism-uk-airport):

> UK activist Muhammad Abdur Rabbani has been charged with obstruction
>   of justice after refusing to provide encryption passwords to police at
>   an airport stop in London. He is due to appear in court in
>   Westminster, England on June 20th.
>
> Rabbani is being charged under the UK’s controversial Terrorism Act,
>   which allows police to compel British subjects to turn over passwords
>   to encrypted devices. Rabbani was initially stopped in November, and
>   arrested when he refused to provide passwords to local police.

Comment: Yes I am a little surprise. However also I followed up and did a check and the law seems to indicate specifically the officer **only** has the right to do so if the person `is or has been concerned in the commission, preparation or instigation of acts of terrorism.` and not just regular immigration trying to determine if one is a genuine visitor. http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/11/section/40

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie In the UK there is also the RIPA act which allows just about anyone and his dog to force you to disclose passwords and encryption keys.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie The powers under that Act have been used in a broader context, including against journalists only in transit through Heathrow. For instance, David Miranda, the spouse of a journalist with links to Edward Snowden, was [detained and questioned for several hours under that Act in 2013](http://bbc.in/2stAQjn). Encrypted information was seized from him. The [Court of Appeal granted a Certificate of Incompatibility](http://bit.ly/1Qb5j9g) in early 2016, declaring that the law was incompatible with Mr Miranda's Human Rights, but Parliament has yet to take any action to amend it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, this is a follow up answer with the result of the case.

On September 26th 2017, [Muhammed Abdur Rabbani was convicted](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-41394156) of obstruction of justice for failing to supply police with the password or PIN for his electronic devices.

> Senior District Judge Emma Arbuthnot rejected the defence, saying he had taken a "calculated risk" to refuse yet again to hand over the Pin and password, despite being warned.
>
> She handed him a conditional discharge - meaning that nothing more will happen if he commits no crime for the next 12 months - and ordered him to pay £600 in costs and a £20 victim surcharge.

His electronic devices have been retained by the Metropolitan Police Force for ongoing examination.

***This pretty much puts significant weight behind the lawfulness of the ability for the police to require you to hand over your passwords and PINs at a UK border, under [Schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/11/schedule/7).***