# What powers do US authorities have to search electronic devices at the border?

Tags: borders, electronic-items

I'm referring here to situations in which people are seeking to enter or re-enter the US. Here I mean border to include airports. I'm interested not just in what powers the authorities technically have but how these powers are generally applied. Related question about the UK [is here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95264/uk-border-crossing-and-electronic-privacy-what-do-i-need-to-know-as-a-visitor).

By search I mean access the contents of the devices by requiring the owners to turn them on and log in to facebook (etc) accounts.

Presumably also the answer would be different for US citizens vs non-US citizens. I assume that non-US citizens are free to decline access to electronic devices (including social media accounts), but in return border authorities are free to decline entry. In practice how commonly do such situations occur? Is it very rare for tourists to be asked to provide access to electronic devices? What has happened when they refuse to do so?

With regard to US citizens, what happens if they just flat out refuse to unlock any device or to comply in any way?

What about green card holders and any US non-citizens with some residency rights?

Comment: Police doesn’t have _any_ rights to search anything, unless they have a warrant. Do you mean _Custom and Border Protection_ agents?

Comment: This issues tends to be way over complicated and dramatized.  It's very simple, everything crossing the border is subject to inspection.  **Everything.**  Your phone is no different than your luggage and citizenship is not all that relevant.